# NGINX path separator/parsing

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

In Apache (without mod_rewrite) I could utilize URI's such as this:

```
/module/erp/service.php/application/workorder/list?start=0&limit=25
```

What do I have to configure or change to support this with NGINX?

```
server {
        listen   80;

        root /usr/share/nginx/www/web/public;
        index index.php index.html;

        server_name apps.mydomain.com;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }


        #error_page 404 /404.html;
        #error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        #location = /50x.html {
        #       root /usr/share/nginx/www;
        #}

        location ~ \.php$ {
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                include fastcgi_params;
        }

}
```

Can someone show me what I might need to add in order to achieve this requirement?

p.s-I need to populate the $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'] just as Apache does as well...

EDIT |

I believe I found my answer here:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/164627/nginx-php-fpm-access-denied-error

I then encountered "access denied" which sounds like the resolve is here:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/164627/nginx-php-fpm-access-denied-error

Any ideas???

Answer (score 0):

OK the links I provided above walked me through the process of resolving my issue with odd URI configuration.

The issue was the **cgi.fix_pathinfo=0**

Most articles I read suggest this is a gapping security hole -- in the case where one might have uploads. I do not have uploads enabled.

http://wiki.nginx.org/PHPFcgiExample

Security trade-off? Perhaps...in my case it wasn't as important as the URI handling as Apache did.